# recluster.cons function and colorful dendrogram

Tags: r, plot, dendrogram

I created a dendrogram using the 'recluster.cons' function of the recluster package. I would like to know how to color the branches of the dendrogram by group resulting from this function.

```
tree <- recluster.cons(sp2, p=1)$cons # sp2 is a presence-absence matrix
plot(tree, direction="downwards")
```

Here is the current dendrogram:

[image: Dendogram generated]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define how many clusters you want to get from the clustering (like cutree), and then using `dendextend` seems like an easier option. First I simulate a dataset that might look like yours:

```
library(recluster)
set.seed(222)
testdata = lapply(1:3,function(i){
truep = runif(200)
replicate(7,rbinom(200,size=1,prob=truep))
})
testdata = t(do.call(cbind,testdata))
rownames(testdata) = paste0(rep(letters[1:3],each=7),rep(1:7,3))
```

We plot it, 3 clusters of sites because it was simulated as such:

```
tree <- recluster.cons(sp2, p=1)$cons # sp2 is a presence-absence matrix
plot(tree,direction="downwards")
```

[image]

Then colour it:

```
dendextend
dend <- color_branches(as.dendrogram(tree),k=3)
plot(dend)
```

[image]